# Bucketing of variable length sequences input for RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Assume a recurrent neural net with variable length sequences of text as input.  To achieve efficiency, one can batch together sequences of similar lengths to minimize the amount of padding per batch--called bucketting.  How can this be implemented in Keras?

For reference, the [Tensorflow Seq2Seq tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/tutorials/seq2seq) which uses [legacy ops](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py) contains this, but its code should be able to be simplified in Keras with fewer lines of code.